# How to use xrandr to fix overscan on a old samsung TV?

Tags: xrandr, overscan

I just installed Ubuntu and my monitor is having a issue with overscan in the Y axis, more or less, 150 pixels. I tried using my TV control but i had no success. Using Windows works fine, so i guess it should be possible in Linux.

Comment: Please investigate further the menus on your TV set. You should be able to do "1:1 pixel mapping".

Answer (score 0):

you could try this

```
xrandr --output HDMI-1 --set underscan on
```

If this does not work kindly post the output of xrandr

Comment: It works, but i get black bars in my screen. Left, right and bottom. Therefore, the resolution gets a bit smaller.

Comment: Can you show that with some pictures

Comment: https://ibb.co/jhb9cMq
https://ibb.co/H4CZSFH

Here.

Comment: okay  you can try `xrandr --output HDMI-1 --set "scaling mode" "Full aspect" ` or  `xrandr --output HDMI-1 --auto`  or `xrandr --output HDMI-1 --set underscan on --auto`